# Azure IoT SDK build gives error

Tags: linux, azure, iot, beagleboneblack

I am trying to wok with Azure IoT in Beagebone black in Debian linux.

While building the SDK it gives the error.
 I am following the same code in Git. I did not modify anything.

Please help me to solve this.
Please see the screenshot of the error
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnmtz.png)

Comment: I build the SDK successfully on my Debian virtual machine. Make sure you have [installed these packages](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-gateway-sdk/blob/master/doc/devbox_setup.md#set-up-a-linux-development-environment).